# SQL : matching two tables with two possibles conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, join

is there a way in SQL while we join two tables table_A and table_B, if we can’t match the two tables on a criteria said criteria_X at all we will try the second criteria criteria_Y

Something like this:

```
select *
from table_A, table_B
where table_A.id = table_B.id2
and (if there is no row where table_B.criteria_X = X then try table_B.criteria_Y = Y)
```

The following query is not a solution:

```
..
and (table_B.criteria_X = X OR table_B.criteria_Y = Y)
```

Thanks

Comment: Why isn't the second query a solution?

Comment: Because I will get two rows, one that matchs criteria_X, and another criteria_Y and my aim is to get only one

Answer (score 0):

This is a *find the best match* query:

```
select * 
from
 (
   select *,
      row_number() -- based on priority, #1 criteria_X, #2 criteria_Y 
      over (partition by table_A.id 
            order by case when table_B.criteria_X = X then 1
                          else 2
                     end) as best_match
   from table_A, table_B
   where table_A.id = table_B.id2
   and (table_B.criteria_X = X OR table_B.criteria_Y = Y)
 ) dt
where best_match = 1
```

If the `OR`ed condition results in loosing indexed access you might try splitting it into two `UNION ALL` selects.

Answer (score 0):

A typical method uses `left join` twice . . . once for each criterion.  Then then uses `coalesce()` in the `select`.  And, with indexes on the join keys, this also should have very good performance:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b1.colx, b2.colx)
from table_A a left join
     table_B b1
     on a.id = b1.id2 and b1.criteria_X = X left join
     table_B b2
     on a.id = b1.id2 and b2.criteria_Y = Y 
where b1.id2 is not null or b2.id2 is not null;
```

The `where` clause ensures that at least one row matches.

This does not work under all circumstances -- in particular, each join needs to return only 0 or 1 matching rows.  This is often the situation with this type of "priority" joins.

An alternative version uses `row_number()`.  This is sort of similar to @dnoeth's approach, but the row number calculation is done before the join:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b1.colx, b2.colx)
from table_A a join
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id2
                                order by (case when criteria_x = X then 1
                                               when criteria_y = Y then 2
                                          end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from table_B b
      where criteria_x = X or criteria_y = Y
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id2 and seqnum = 1
```